# Cannot run all tests in visual studio. Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Missing Operator '|' or '&'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

The following is error info.
I changed real method name and application name to the format like `[TestMethod1Name]`.

```
Log level is set to Informational (Default).
Test data store opened in 0.232 sec.
---------- Starting test discovery for requested test run ----------
No test is available in D:\Source\Repos\Core\[applicationName].dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
========== Test discovery finished: 489 Tests found in 5.6 sec ==========
---------- Starting test run ----------
Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Missing Operator '|' or '&'. Specify the correct format and try again. Note that the incorrect format can lead to no test getting executed.
No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=[TestMethod1Name]|FullyQualifiedName=[TestMethod2Name]|...` in D:\Source\Repos\Core\[myapplication].dll
```

For test framework, I adopt `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

It's no problem to run any one TestClass or TestMethod but cannot run all tests

Comment: "Incorrect format for TestCaseFilter Missing Operator '|' or '&" - sounds like your problem

Answer (score 1):

in unit test you cant change the name of [TestMethod] this static name and refer to found test method but you can naming your method like:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void yourmethodname()
    {

    }
```